# Can I use a list in mail.To with win32com.client outlook?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I need to use a list of emails to send my message, but when I use mail.To = list, show an error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We need to see your code (not just `To = list`) and the actual error, not just "an error".

Answer (score 0):

You really need to show the relevant snippet of your code and include the exact error.
The `MailItem.To` property must be set to a ";" separated list of names or addresses.